# Inserir marcadores coloridos no datepick usando angularjs, ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-3, datepicker

Como faço pra inserir marcadores coloridos no `datepick` usando `AngularJS` e `ui-bootstrap`?

**Página:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
      <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="newjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
         <div  tyle="display:inline-block" style="width:  310px;">
            <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" 
               show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('app').controller('DatepickerCtrl', function ($scope) {

//  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
//    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
//  };
    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.maxDate = new Date(2015, 12, 12);
    };
});
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema.

Sugiro que leio os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comentei o exemplo que está na [documentação](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) do `ui-bootstrap` pra tentar exemplificar pra você como funciona.

Aqui está o exemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9pdjzpEHx1jhZsapbcjS?p=preview

Repare que nesse exemplo tem dois eventos:

```
 //Marca um evento para amanhã
  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

  //Marca um evento pra depois de depois de amanhã kkk rsrs ou seja 3 dias depois
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
```

Ambas variáveis recebem a data atual, porém uma incrementa + 1 dia e a outra + 2. Dessa forma os eventos(marcadores) que você quer irá ser exibido no calendário. Faça um teste depois e altere esses valores pra +4, +5, etc.. Que então você entenderá melhor.

Em seguida os eventos são passados pra uma lista:

//lista com os eventos, onde date é data e status representa a prioridade(a corzinha)

```
  $scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'partially'
      }
    ];
```

Então é só colocar o `datepicker` em sua página:

```
<uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></uib-datepicker>
```

o destaque vai para a diretiva `custom-class` onde chamamos o método que monta os eventos no calendário:

```
//Preenche o calendário com os eventos
  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
```

Faça alguns testes nesse `plnkr` e tente entender entender o funcionamento de tudo, dessa forma você poderá trabalhar em cima desse código conforme sua necessidade.